# Fraction Creation Errors

Tags: java

I made the same set code just a day ago and it was working perfectly.
Now it gets a ton of errors that I dont understand.
Can someone help? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.Math;
import type.lib.*;

public class Fraction
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        print.println("For each fraction enter its numerator/denominator,");
        print.println("pressing ENTER after each");
        print.println("Enter x");
        Fraction a = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
        print.println("Enter y");
        Fraction b = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
        a.add(b);
        Fraction a = x;
        print.println("Enter z");
        Fraction c = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
        print.println("Enter t");
        Fraction d = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
        c.add(d);
        Fraction c = y;
        x.divide(y);
        print.println("A = ");
        print.println(x.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which errors do you want help understanding?  My psychic powers aren't working very well today.

Comment: Try changing `Fraction a = x;` to `Fraction x = a;` and `Fraction c = y;` to `Fraction y = c;`.

Comment: @DavidWallace, nice psychic powers.

Comment: I wonder if you might show your Fraction object code and then we might actually be able to verify that @DavidWallace gave you the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes, and also create the methods that u r using like add and divide

```
public class Fraction {
        public Fraction(long nextLong, long nextLong2) {  // add the constructor

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
            print.println("For each fraction enter its numerator/denominator,");
            print.println("pressing ENTER after each");
            print.println("Enter x");
            Fraction a = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
            print.println("Enter y");
            Fraction b = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
            a.add(b);
            Fraction x = a;  // change the fraction places
            print.println("Enter z");
            Fraction c = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
            print.println("Enter t");
            Fraction d = new Fraction(scan.nextLong(),scan.nextLong());
            c.add(d);     //create add method
            Fraction y =c;   // change the fraction places
            x.divide(y);   // create divide method
            print.println("A = ");
            print.println(x.toString());
        }

//Create the required methods..
private void divide(Fraction y) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        private void add() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```